# Is it possible with std::atomic, make a complex member function of a class atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

Is it possible to make something like this?

```
...
class test{
int i;
public:
      test(int k):i(k){};
      void my(){
         cout<<i;
      }
}
atomic<test> kk(0);
kk.test();
...
```

If this is not possible then how to make a call of function so that it will was atomic?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Thanks, i tried this and it doesn`t work that way. In kk there is no member function test. So i don`t know how to call it. So asking. How to call test from kk???

Comment: If you want atomic functions you need to use a mutex.  `atomic<>` only gives you [a few operations on integers of various sizes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). It won't magically make a function with more than a single integer operator atomic.

Comment: @user2470734 Now that you know that you cannot do it, you should rephrase your question.

Comment: I think this will be great, if all was so simple...

Comment: `std::atomic<Ty>` is well-defined for arbitrary types `Ty` provided they can be copied with `memcpy` and compared for equality with `memcmp`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: yes, but the resulting type will only provide `load()`, `store()`, `exchange()`, `compare_exchange()`, and `is_lock_free()`.  And `is_lock_free()` will return `false` on almost every architecture.  It won't help at all with OP's question, which wants to make arbitrary function calls on `Ty` atomic.  You can only do that by using an explicit `mutex`.

Comment: @WanderingLogic - `std::atomic<Ty>` can be lock free whenever the size of the stored object is small enough. The implementation I wrote for Dinkumware uses size in all cases, including numeric types, to determine whether to use a lock. Regardless, I was responding to the assertion that "`atomic<>` only gives you a few operations on integers of various sizes". That's too narrow.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Ah, got it.  I was just trying to make sure that OP got the point that `atomic` is completely inappropriate for the problem at hand, thus emphasizing what it can't do, rather than what it can.  It is very cool that I can do a (truly atomic) `compare_exchange()` on an 8-byte struct when I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that `std::atomic` works is that it uses certain instructions provided by the processor. These instructions are ONLY available for integers of certain sizes (different processors have different limits and rules about what you can and can't do, and in some architectures, the processor architecture may even require the use of a mutex or similar functionality simply to implement std::atomic).

Note also that the purpose of `std::atomic` is used to ensure that the value is updated atomically across multiple processor cores or multiple processors, which is not typically what you want/can to do with larger data structures.

To achieve atomic operations on other data structures, you will have to use mutex or similar constructs to ensure that the processing is done in an "thread atomic" way (different from "processor atomic").

Comment: 31.8 [atomics.types.generic] of the C++ spec doesn't say anything about a size limitation. Only that it's trivially copy and move construct and assignable.
Also note the `static constexpr bool is_always_lock_free = implementation-defined;` member.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** create `std::atomic` objects that hold non-numeric objects. The main restriction is that the contained type has to be trivially copyable; loosely speaking (because this is how it's implemented), this means that copying with `memcpy` is okay, and comparing with `memcmp` is meaningful. However, it doesn't let you call member functions on the stored object. You have to copy the stored object, do the update, then copy the result back into the atomic object.

Comment: In OP's example, what is failing is the call `kk.test()`.  `atomic` is completely irrelevant to making the `test()` function execute correctly without read-modify-update atomicity problems.

Comment: @WanderingLogic - that's what my last two sentences say.