# Is there an atomic lambda expression?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stl, atomic

I'd like to define a mutex and execute a lambda expression on it. Is there a way to do this concisely in STL?

What I'm looking for:

```
  std::atomic<MyPointer*> myAtomic;
  myAtomic.call([&](int var1, int var2) { /* some code */ }, val1, val2);
```

What I'm not looking for:

```
  std::mutex myMutex;
  MyPointer* myPointer = new MyPointer();
  myMutex.lock();
  // some code
  myMutex.unlock();
```

Basically, I want atomic to take a lambda expression and lock/unlock before/after calling it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want this? What is the general use case of this code?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Synchronized.md

Comment: Short answer is "no".   `std::atomic` does not support any operations that grab a mutex, call a function specified by the caller, and then release the mutex.     If you really want to do such a thing implement your own class to give the required logic.   I doubt there's a need - your only motivation seems to be avoiding wrapping code in a mutex.

Comment: I don't get it. What is `myAtomic.call`?  Atomics have `store` and `load`, but no `call`. The variable `myAtomic` is a pointer to a `MyPointer`. What properties does `MyPointer` have?  Where does a mutex figure in? Be more scrutible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible with std::atomic, make a complex member function of a class atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023052/is-it-possible-with-stdatomic-make-a-complex-member-function-of-a-class-atomi)

Comment: Using atomics inside a region of code that is locked by a mutex is usually pointless; locking and unlocking the mutex gives you all the benefits of atomic access but at a higher cost. Use one or the other, depending on what you actually need.

Answer (score 3):

Atomic is there to handle atomically the operations defined in its interface.

So you could have an atomic pointer and ensure its value gets atomically incremented or replaced. You could even have an atomic object of your own type, that is then ensured to be atomically copied. Atomic may use atomic cpu operations or any kind of locking behind the scene to comply with the specifications (implementation dependent).

But the atomicity doesn't extend to objects pointed to, nor to any other state changing operation invoked on the atomic object.

So the answer is no, You'll have to use mutexes, preferably through [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) (so to ensure lock release even in case of excetions).